# Autofilter in apache POI range not working

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

Does anyone know what could be wrong with the following filter I am trying to set for a report generated with apache POI?

I'm using this code:

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A4:A6"));
```

To get this result:

[image: Filters applied]

However, when I click the arrow to filter my results I also get the value "average" as a possible result in the dropdown list.

[image: Filter list]

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Simply add an empty row between your data area and the footer row.
The data area can be limited by empty rows and columns/header.

Although you've selected `A4:A6`, only `A4` was marked as autofilter ... I'm not sure, but I think, you can only achieve horizontal autofilter via VBA. So `setAutoFilter` should be something like `A4:B4`, as you mark only the header and not the data area.

(tested with POI 3.9, Libre Office 4.0)

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

public class Autofilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        sheet.createRow(3).createCell(0).setCellValue("Protocol Number");
        sheet.createRow(4).createCell(0).setCellValue("DEMONNUMBER1");
        sheet.createRow(5).createCell(0).setCellValue("DEMONNUMBER2");
        sheet.createRow(6).setZeroHeight(true);
        sheet.createRow(7).createCell(0).setCellValue("Average");
        sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A4:B4"));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("autofilter.xls");
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can cofirm that also for apache poi 5.2.3